# Does Dragon Ball: Raging Blast 2 Limited Edition have the original music?

Tags: dragon-ball-raging-blast-2

I bought *Dragon Ball: Raging Blast 2* Classic Edition on the Xbox 360 and was heavily disappointed because the whole music collection was replaced.

I wonder if the Limited Edition is also packed with the "new" lame music or the original one.

*Even though it is stolen from older Dragon Ball games...*

Comment: @Stevoisiak Hi, I’ve noticed that you have been tagging a lot of questions with their game tags. That’s good. However, I’ve also noticed that most of the questions you retagged still have the platform tags, which should have been removed as per [our policy](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4639/4797). Platform tags should only be used for questions that are specifically about the given platform or a game’s interaction with that platform. Questions about a platform-specific game version should not be tagged with the platform tag. Instead, the platform info should be in the question body.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No. It's all going to be the same music.**

**Why?**

The main composer for the raging blast games, and most of DBZ Kai (right up to the Cell games), Kenji Yamamoto, had been hit with a copyright suit for most of the music he composed.

This initially occurred in May 2011, with Koei releasing a statement with the following:

> The existence of multiple suspicious musical pieces which may infringe on the rights of third parties has been confirmed within the musical compositions recorded for “Dragon Ball Kai”, an animated television work produced by this firm. The relevant musical pieces are used as background music in “Dragon Ball Kai”, and measures are promptly being taken to replace the relevant musical pieces from the background music of “Dragon Ball Kai”.
>
> Also, we are proceeding with a swift investigation of the facts, and discussion of countermeasures with concerned parties in the near future.

Almost immediately after this, repeat episodes of Kai had all the music replaced, the games had their music replaced, and it even went so far as to have **Toei remove him from their list of staff, and Kenji to denounce any credit for music made for DBZ**

Some of the musical comparisons that were included in the claim, as well as a retrospective can be found [here](http://www.kanzenshuu.com/features/kenji-yamamoto-retrospective/).

In the end, this caused raging blast 2 to lose the right to use the Kai music, and instead use the Budokai Tenkaichi 2  soundtrack (as stated on the [wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball:_Raging_Blast_2)), which is going to remain the only soundtrack you can hear (unless you find a copy of the game before the suit)

Comment: Then which versions of the game contains the "removed/stolen" music? Only the first Japan releases?

Comment: " in late summer 2011 (nearly a year after the game was originally released), fans who purchased new copies of Raging Blast 2 for the PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 immediately noticed a replacement musical score." So, i think the `Limited Edition` versions not being created more then a year after release, so they will correct the "original/stolen" music, righT?

Comment: @TussLászló yes. Anything after that year will have the new music in it. The one's with the older music are completely gone, unfortunately.